# Counting occurrences of value in range

Tags: excel

This is the first time I am using this website, I hope I am reaching to the right crowd. Let me get straight to my question:

I have some data in a column in excel, say A1:A20. Each one contains a letter and some times some of them get repeated. In a cell of an another column, say C1, I want to calculate the count of a letter (let's say A), but in a way that only every third count of letter A increments count in cell C1 by 1. I have given below an example and I hope you might find that understandable... Thanks :)

[Click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimSQ.jpg)

Comment: Use `COUNTIF`: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/

Comment: Thank you for checking this out John, I did checked that link and found some useful information regarding Excel however I was still unable to get the information I was looking for as I am trying to increase a value in a cell depending on the count of the value when it attains a specific count.

Comment: I don't get at all why the output is 2...

Comment: With your screen-shot: in `C1`: `=INT(COUNTIF(A1:A20,"A")/3)`

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this and thanks for that solution. It did work for me :)

I didn't believed that this site would be this much helpful.... Thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want:

```
=FLOOR(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20;$A1)/3)
```

Paste it in C1 and drag down to C20.

- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) counts occurrences of **second argument** in range specified by **first argument**. The tricky part is that both arguments will be "moving" with you formula as you go down in C rows. I have used dollar signs to make references **absolute**. Here is Microsoft help on this issue: [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21). Search the web for "Excel absolute relative references" if you want to learn more.
- Then count number is divided by three, because you want to have number incremented after "every third count"
- Finally the result of division is wrapped in [`FLOOR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886) function that ensures that result is integer by rounding fractions **down** into nearest whole number. There is also `CEILING` function that rounds **up** and `ROUND` that rounds according to rules they taught us in math class.

Comment: Thanks you for your help with this. I was having a bit of a trouble using your formula to work this out however I was able to get this resolved with the help of Axel Richter. He provided me with this solution "C1: =INT(COUNTIF(A1:A20,"A")/3)"...

I do also appreciate your help for sharing the information about the "Excel absolute relative references". There are certain other issues for which this might be helpful... Thanks once again.